# show background.js data in popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i have a chrome extension which consist of three main files ( Background.js, Popup.js and Popup.html). 
when chrome browser opened, backround.js send a message to a host app and the response store in two array. i want show this arrays in popup.html when extension icon clicked. but how? how popup.js get arrays from background.js to fill popup.html?

Comment: showing some code might be helpful....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime `getBackgroundPage`
from there you can access globals and functions in your background.

a more general solution is to use extension messaging which works also from content scripts.